# Correción de código C++ para el promedio de n números

Tags: c++, funciones, algoritmos

Cuento con este código:

```
#include <iostream>

//A continuacion, nuestro programa calcula el promedio de numero pares e impares del 1 al 500.

using namespace std;

float promedio(int , int);//declaramos nuestra funcion.

int par=0;
float impar=0;

int main()
{
    cout<<"El promedio de numeros pares e impares es:"<<promedio(suma_par,suma_impar)<<endl;

    return 0;
}

int promedio(int suma_par, int suma_impar)
{
    int i;

    for(i==1;i<=500;i++)
    {
        if(i % 2==0)
        {
            int par;
           suma_par= par + i;
            return (suma_par / i);
        }
        else
        {
            int impar;
            suma_impar= impar + i;
            return (suma_impar/ i);
        }
    }
}
```

Se supone que al correrlo me de un promedio de los números impares y pares del 1 al 500

Comment: Que error te sale?

Comment: Por favor especifica más el problema: ¿qué quieres conseguir?¿Qué errores o dudas te encuentras? (¿y dónde?)

Comment: Muestra que error tienes. si es que no te sale el resultado correcto o que?

Comment: Me parece que no tienes muy claro como funcionan las funciones; cuando llamas la función `promedio(suma_par,suma_impar)` los valores suma par y suma impar, pasan hacia la función para que la funcion llos procese y pueda dar una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

versión corta: tu codigo no funciona de entrada, puedes intentar compilarlo para ver todos los errores, pero por ejemplo:

- En el main, utilizas las variables suma_par y suma_impar, las cuales no están definidas.
- La Función de promedio está mal hecha, saldrá de la misma en la primera iteración del ciclo for.
- defines, pero no inicializas las variables par e impar dentro del for.

Al final escribí el codigo desde 0:

```
#include <iostream>

//A continuacion, nuestro programa calcula el promedio de numero pares e impares del 1 al 500.

using namespace std;

float promedio(int b, int l, int s);//declaramos nuestra funcion.

int par=0;
float impar=0;

int main()
{
     cout<<"El promedio de numeros pares es:"<<promedio(2,500,2)<<endl;
     cout<<"El promedio de numeros impares es:"<<promedio(1,499,2)<<endl;

     return 0;
}

float promedio(int base, int limit, int step){
     int i=0;
     float sum=0;

     for(i=base;i<=limit;i+=step){
          sum+=i;
     }
     return sum/((limit-base)/step);
}
```

Comment: Exactamente, la función promedio esta muy mal escrita saldrá a la mitad de la primera iteración por el valor `return (suma_par / i);`